# Problem to extract custom fields data in MS-Booking with Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

Need help. We have 2 problems to extract custom fields data in MS-Booking by using Graph tool. We are near, but some records and/or data are sometimes missing when it wrong ...

1. On the first following command/request :
   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/pouvtech@cegeptroisrivieres.onmicrosoft.com/appointments

   PROBLEM : A lot of customer and appointments data are missing. Most of them are empty like the result below ...

```
{ "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#bookingBusinesses('pouvtech%40cegeptroisrivieres.onmicrosoft.com')/appointments", "value": [ { "id": "AAMkADY2MjA3OGM3LTYwOWUtNGU5NS04YzAxLTE5NTk5MzJhN2I3OQBGAAAAAABCDbBYqWVtR5zSlJwdYN2dBwB4ZfrSVkupTZ_RUHowUU-UAAAAAAENAAB4ZfrSVkupTZ_RUHowUU-UAAALosc9AAA=", "selfServiceAppointmentId": "7e9e8039-2fe1-4369-9107-42f772503915", "additionalInformation": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from html -->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n", "isLocationOnline": false, "onlineMeetingUrl": null, "customerId": null, "customerName": null, "customerEmailAddress": null, "customerPhone": null, "customerNotes": null, "serviceId": "b0da8ff4-aa62-4b04-ab6e-39ba3072ee4a", "serviceName": "Techniques de soins infirmiers", "duration": "PT45M", "preBuffer": "PT0S", "postBuffer": "PT0S", "priceType": "undefined", "price": 0, "serviceNotes": null, "optOutOfCustomerEmail": false, "staffMemberIds": [ "52637fe9-a068-4da1-aeed-a08cfc3b105f" ], "invoiceAmount": 0, "invoiceId": null, "invoiceStatus": "draft", "invoiceUrl": null, "invoiceDate": null, "customerLocation": { "displayName": "", "locationEmailAddress": null, "locationUri": "", "locationType": null, "uniqueId": null, "uniqueIdType": null, "address": { "type": "home", "postOfficeBox": "", "street": "", "city": "", "state": "", "countryOrRegion": "", "postalCode": "" }, "coordinates": { "altitude": null, "latitude": null, "longitude": null, "accuracy": null, "altitudeAccuracy": null } }, "start": { "dateTime": "2020-11-04T17:30:00-05:00", "timeZone": "America/New_York" }, "end": { "dateTime": "2020-11-04T18:15:00-05:00", "timeZone": "America/New_York" }, "serviceLocation": { "displayName": "En ligne", "locationEmailAddress": null, "locationUri": "", "locationType": null, "uniqueId": null, "uniqueIdType": null, "address": { "type": "home", "postOfficeBox": "", "street": "", "city": "", "state": "", "countryOrRegion": "", "postalCode": "" }, "coordinates": { "altitude": null, "latitude": null, "longitude": null, "accuracy": null, "altitudeAccuracy": null } }, "reminders": [] },
```

2. On the second following command/request :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/pouvtech@cegeptroisrivieres.onmicrosoft.com/events/AAMkADY2MjA3OGM3LTYwOWUtNGU5NS04YzAxLTE5NTk5MzJhN2I3OQBGAAAAAABCDbBYqWVtR5zSlJwdYN2dBwB4ZfrSVkupTZ_RUHowUU-UAAAAAAENAAB4ZfrSVkupTZ_RUHowUU-UAAAOTblRAAA=?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter%3Did eq 'Binary {ccb88e73-951a-4b10-bb49-e6628b8d8494} Name BookingItemAnsweredCustomQuestions')
```

PROBLEM : Custom fields data are sometimes missing because customer/appointments ID are missing like seen above. So, most of custom fields data are missing. We obtained 2 results on more than 100 appointments.

Can you help us ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you are adding the customers data and creating appoimntments?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Data are entered by the Booking interface. There is no other way used like import or integration. We use Graph only to try to extract custom fileds data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this  because singleValueExtendedProperties only works with 1-1 appointments in MS Bookings. I think you have multiple slots enabled in which case it only brings back the custom fields for the first slot in the booking. I have had the same issue and currently there is no work around I know of.

Comment: You are right. This is exactly the problem. We finally have the confirmation from Microsoft.No fix no development before late 2021. Thank you for your help mjroodt